# How to use ffmpeg.wasm client side

Tags: vue.js, ffmpeg, webassembly

I am looking to use [ffmpeg.wasm](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm) in a serverless Vue app, but have no idea how to integrate it. Ideally I want to use it to stitch together `Canvas HTMLElement` into a video output that the user can download. If anyone can make a JSFiddle, Codepen or whatever other medium demo, that would be great. Working off of [this example](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/vue-app/blob/main/src/App.vue) I am not sure how to add a Canvas element as a frame to a file and then createURL for the resulting file.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/vue-app)?

Comment: Similar but I am not sure how to add a Canvas element as a frame to a .gif or other extension video file.